# Why am I getting a can't load class, when the class is in my JAR file?

Tags: java, jboss, jar, webservice-client, webservices-client

I'm running JBoss 4.2.3.GA (can't change this version) and Java 6.  I'm tryhing to deploy a JAR file.  Within it, I'm attempting to connect to a web service, but am getting the error, "Cannot load java type: org.mainco.bsorg.BusinessServiceFaultException," even though the class in question is within the JAR file I'm deploying to the server.  I'm thinking there is some kind of class loader issue, but don't know where to start looking.  The Java code I use to connect is

```
final OrganizationService service = new OrganizationService(wsdl, qname);           
service.getOrganizationServicePort()
```

I'm generating my web service client code using the Maven plugin below ...

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>${wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                        <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        <packageName>org.mainco.bsorg</packageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and I have these dependencies ...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the exception.  Any ideas where I need to start digging?

```
2012-08-13 12:45:02,522 ERROR [org.quartz.core.ErrorLogger] Job (default.job.0.1344875788431 threw an exception.
org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Cannot load java type: org.mainco.bsorg.BusinessServiceFaultException]
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:214)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
* Nested Exception (Underlying Cause) ---------------
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Cannot load java type: org.mainco.bsorg.BusinessServiceFaultException
        at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.Ejb3TxPolicy.handleInCallerTx(Ejb3TxPolicy.java:87)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:130)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:195)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:249)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:268)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:138)
        at $Proxy80.execute(Unknown Source)
        at org.jboss.resource.adapter.quartz.inflow.QuartzJob.execute(QuartzJob.java:57)
        at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:203)
        at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.jboss.ws.WSException: Cannot load java type: org.mainco.bsorg.BusinessServiceFaultException
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.FaultMetaData.getJavaType(FaultMetaData.java:151)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.DynamicWrapperGenerator.generate(DynamicWrapperGenerator.java:139)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.addFault(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:324)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.processWebMethod(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:797)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.processWebMethods(JAXWSMetaDataBuilder.java:891)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.builder.jaxws.JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.rebuildEndpointMetaData(JAXWSClientMetaDataBuilder.java:300)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPortInternal(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:271)
        at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.spi.ServiceDelegateImpl.getPort(ServiceDelegateImpl.java:202)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:143)
        at org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationService.getOrganizationServicePort(OrganizationService.java:56)
        at org.mainco.subco.orgsclient.quartz.UpdateOrgsJob.execute(UpdateOrgsJob.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:112)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.InvocationContextImpl.proceed(InvocationContextImpl.java:166)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.invoke(EJB3InterceptorsInterceptor.java:63)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:54)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
        at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:101)
        at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: No ClassLoaders found for: org.mainco.bsorg.BusinessServiceFaultException
        at org.jboss.mx.loading.LoadMgr3.beginLoadTask(LoadMgr3.java:212)
        at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClassImpl(RepositoryClassLoader.java:521)
        at org.jboss.mx.loading.RepositoryClassLoader.loadClass(RepositoryClassLoader.java:415)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.wsf.common.JavaUtils.loadJavaType(JavaUtils.java:143)
        at org.jboss.ws.metadata.umdm.FaultMetaData.getJavaType(FaultMetaData.java:138)
```

**Edit:** I'm deploying the JAR file to $JBOSS_HOME/server/default/deploy .  The JAR file contains a Quartz job that I want to run, which is why I'm saving it to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the jar that you have is the correct version and if you have that jar file on the jboss lib folder (It's C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\seam\lib here)
*seam = the name of the profile you're using